# glActiveTexture in Qt and QGLWidget?

Tags: qt, opengl, glew, qglwidget, qt5.3

I have a small application on OpenGL+GLEW. Now, I am trying to rewrite it with QT(instead of GLEW). But I have a problem.
IDE writes:

`'glActiveTexture' was not declared in this scope
     glActiveTexture(TextureUnit);
                                ^`

Here is that code in .cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "texture.h"

Texture::Texture(GLenum TextureTarget, std::string& FileName)
{
    m_textureTarget = TextureTarget;
    m_fileName      = FileName;
}

bool Texture::Load()
{
    // A lot of code for reading the picture.
}

void Texture::Bind(GLenum TextureUnit)
{
    glActiveTexture(TextureUnit);
    glBindTexture(m_textureTarget, m_textureObj);
}
```

Here is code from .h file.

```
#ifndef TEXTURE_H
#define TEXTURE_H

#include <string>
#include <QGLWidget>

class Texture
{
public:
    Texture(GLenum TextureTarget, std::string& FileName);

    bool Load();

    void Bind(GLenum TextureUnit);

private:
    std::string m_fileName;
    GLenum m_textureTarget;
    GLuint m_textureObj;
    unsigned int width, height;
    unsigned char * data;
};


#endif  /* TEXTURE_H */
```

I am starting to think that Qt doesn't present such capabilities. 
How can I solve this problem?
I would be glad to any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anything beyond GL 1.1 (and `glActiveTexture` is beyond that), you have to use OpenGL's extension mechanism. Qt can do that for you all under the hood, have a look at the [`QAbstractOpenGLFunctions`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractopenglfunctions.html) class hierarchy

You can get the context the widget has created via [`QOpenGLWidget::context`](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.4/qopenglwidget.html#context) and the QAbstractOpenGLFunctions of the context via [`QOpenGLContext::versionFunctions()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglcontext.html#versionFunctions-2). There is also the older [`QOpenGLFunctions`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglfunctions.html) class available via [`QOpenGLContext::functions()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglcontext.html#functions) which is limited to GL ES 2.0 (and the smathcing ubset of desktop GL 2.0), but would be enough for `glActiveTexture()`.

Comment: Should I just add `#include` and write something like `QOpenGLFunctions_4_3_Core::glActiveTexture(TextureUnit);`. Or does it work in a unusual way?

Comment: Read the documentation I linked. You cannot just use this statically. These pointers have to be queried at runtime, after the GL context was created.

Comment: @user3051029: maybe you also find also [this blog post](http://www.kdab.com/opengl-in-qt-5-1-part-1/) helpful (especially the "Functions, functions everywhere!" section).

Comment: The old class actually loads glActiveTexture only on GLES 2 capable systems in release build. Debug build somehow does in any case, but release got null pointer